# String that matches hardware and OS

Tags: software-installation

I was just wondering:
http://support.stockfishchess.org/kb/advanced-topics/compiling-stockfish-on-linux
here, on the second step, it says to type a string that matches hardware and OS. I need help with that, but also, whenever I type in `make profile-build ubuntu=x86-32` (which I can only assume is correct) it gives me the following error

```
steven@Longitude063D:~$ make profile-build ubuntu=x86-32
make: *** No rule to make target `profile-build'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Or you could just `sudo apt-get install stockfish`, although the one in the repos is version 4 while the latest one is version 6.

Comment: i did that, but how do i run stockfish? thanks!

Comment: You'll have to open a terminal and run the `stockfish` command.

Answer (score 4):

The example is `make build ARCH=x86-64`. `ARCH` is a variable, not the name of the distro (even though Arch Linux is a distro). Run `uname -m`. If the output is `x86_64`, then run:

```
make build ARCH=x86-64
```

If it is `i686` or `i386`, run:

```
make build ARCH=x86-32
```

Lastly, it looks like you are running `make` in the wrong directory. You should be running `make` in the `src` folder of `Stockfish`.

Comment: ok, thanks! just curious though, how do i do that? (sorry- i just installed ubuntu a week ago)

Comment: Use `cd` to change the directory you're in. For example, `cd Downloads`.